# I can RDP to any PC on a network via VPN, apart from ONE PC

Tags: vpn, remote-access, remote-desktop, openvpn

So we have a team at works who manages the firewall. To connect to the network, we use openVPN, which assigns us with an IP to enter the network.

Whilst connected via VPN, I can ping every single machine (including my own), and I can rdp to every PC (excluding my own). This is the problem. I have asked a colleague to try to ping and RDP to my machine from their home via VPN, and they can. So it's a problem with my machine. (My machine is running windows 11.)

Any tips?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured it out... Someone in my house had the same IP as the machine at work. I had to change my subnet to a different one to my local ethernet and the one provided by via the VPN for it to work. Because instead of pinging the VPN server then the host machine, it was straight up pinging the person in this house lol.